# How can i enable libmongoc ssl?

Tags: linux, centos7, plesk, php-7.2

Im using plesk 12 and PHP7 on centos 7.
How can i enable libmongoc ssl on my server?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to compile it with

yum install git plesk-php70-devel make gcc openssl-devel

git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git

cd mongo-php-driver/

git submodule update --init

/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/phpize

./configure --with-php-config=/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php-config --with-mongodb-ssl=openssl

make

cp /root/mongo-php-driver/modules/mongodb.so /opt/plesk/php/7.0/lib/php/modules/

plesk bin php_handler --reread

After that in phpinfo() you will see:

libmongoc SSL   enabled

libmongoc SSL library   OpenSSL

libmongoc crypto    enabled

libmongoc crypto library    libcrypto

Comment: how can we do this for apache?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working in php-fpm (7.1) Docker using below commands. What's important is to install `libssl-dev` before installing mongodb driver.

`apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev
pecl install mongodb
echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini`

Comment: Thanks, @pramod for the prompt fixes to the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @pramod. I just tried your snippet with PHP 8 and it works fine!